# SD Card damaged by DBAN

Tags: micro-sd-card, dban

In order to wipe external storage of my android, I put the SD card in laptop and ran DBAN. It has become blank but not readable by mobile or laptop. Mobile says"SD card blank or has unsupported file system". formatting it does not help. Laptop does not open the card at all. Anyhelp to make it usable again?

Comment: Does your computer OS report capacity/partitions/filesystem/anything correctly? Note that SD cards does not need partition tables or any other kind of MBR to work, however some devices (_don't know about android_) require that SD card has MBR in order to successfully recognize partitions and filesystems.

Comment: Laptop OS reports capacity wrongly,for eg,  for all partitions, UBUNTU says "320gb Hard drive:Work" . where "work" is name of partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not readable because DBAN doesn't format the card. It wipes the card using a mathematically random sequence of writes. Format the SD card.

Comment: as i said formatting did not help.

Comment: do SD Cards contain some codes in it, which has been erased ?

Comment: No. They don't have any special codes. I don't recall seeing your comment about formatting before. Are you sure you successfully formatted the card? The slide/switch for the SD card is set to read/write or unprotect(ed)?

Comment: android formats it without any error

Comment: Try formatting in FAT32.

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: I formatted it in ubuntu with MBR and then android showed it as damaged storage and asked to format. formatted in android 2-3 times and it breathed its second life :)